# Necessity and sufficiency of Euler-Lagrange equations in making an integral stationary

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, action, variational-calculus, functional-derivatives

Suppose we want to make an integral $S$ of the form $$S = \int_{x_1}^{x_2} f\left[y_1(x), \dots, y_n(x), y'_1(x), \dots, y'_n(x), x\right]dx$$ stationary with the constraint $y_1\left(x_1\right) = \tilde{y}_1, \dots, y_n(x_1) = \tilde{y}_n, y_1\left(x_2\right) = \bar{y}_1, \dots, y_n(x_2) = \bar{y}_n$. Is it *necessary*, *sufficient*, or *necessary and sufficient* for the $y_1(x), \dots, y_n(x)$ to satisfy the $n$ Euler-Lagrange equations, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_1} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'_1}, \dots,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_n} = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'_n},$$ in order to make $S$ stationary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necessary and sufficient, because [stationary paths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point) are *by definition* paths where the [functional/variational derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative) vanishes, i.e. [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) are satisfied.